# MySQL update using inner join on a nested query

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I'm trying to do this: look up a `resource_id` from a table `items`, which has `asset_id` and `resource_id`, and use it to set the `resource_id` field in another table, `elements`, which also has `asset_id` and `resource_id`.

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.resource_id = t2.resource_id 
FROM elements t1 INNER JOIN
( SELECT asset_id, resource_id 
  FROM items 
  WHERE resource_id is not null
  GROUP BY asset_id ) t2 
ON t1.asset_id = t2.asset_id;
```

I'm getting the very vague message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near 'FROM elements t1 INNER JOIN
( SELECT asset_id, resource_id 
  FROM items' at line 2
```

This is in MySQL 5.6.27.  Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks, Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, your syntax is wrong. Try this:

```
UPDATE elements as t1  
INNER JOIN
( SELECT asset_id, resource_id 
  FROM items 
  WHERE resource_id is not null
  GROUP BY asset_id ) t2 
ON t1.asset_id = t2.asset_id
SET t1.resource_id = t2.resource_id
```

Comment: ah, i was missing the "AS" then?  I know that the error says that my syntax is wrong, but that's an unhelpfully vague error message.  It might as well just say "there is a problem" or something.  Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE elements AS t1,
(SELECT asset_id, resource_id 
  FROM items 
  WHERE resource_id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY asset_id 
  ) AS t2 
 SET t1.resource_id = t2.resource_id 
 WHERE t1.asset_id = t2.asset_id;